# Generate QRCode without Windows-1252

Tags: qr-code, google-authentication

Hi I using to generate QR code [BaconQrCode](https://github.com/Bacon/BaconQrCode). I have problem with gereate QR code to [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2).

To generate QR code I use: [GoogleAuthenticator](https://github.com/PHPGangsta/GoogleAuthenticator)

BaconQrCode generate QR code with characters for example:

> otpauth%3A%2F%2Ftotp%2FLaravel%3Fsecret%3D3DNLF33LLMG7SN2XXX%26issuer%3Dname.surname%2540mydomain.com

I check and work in Google Authenticator this code:

> otpauth://totp/Laravel?secret=3DNLF33LLMG7SN2XXX&issuer=name.surname%40mydomain.com

Comment: I don't really see a question. Please try to explain what your expected result is and what's wrong with your actual result.

Comment: @DTul I need genareta QRCode without `Windows-1252` characters. I need normal characters.

Answer (score 0):

I change fucntion `getQRCodeGoogleUrl`:

```
public function getQRCodeGoogleUrl($name, $secret, $title = null, $params = array())
{
    $level = !empty($params['level']) && array_search($params['level'], array('L', 'M', 'Q', 'H')) !== false ? $params['level'] : 'M';
    if ($title !== null) {
        $getTitle = $title;
    }
    $urlencoded = "otpauth://totp/$name?secret=$secret&issuer=$getTitle&ecc=$level";
    return $urlencoded;
}
```

and the I use `BaconQrCodeGenerator`:

```
$google_qrCodeUrl = $this->getQRCodeGoogleUrl($title, $secret, $mail);
$qrcode = new BaconQrCodeGenerator;
$qrCodeUrl = $qrcode->size(250)->generate($google_qrCodeUrl);
```

And now work correctly ;)